# How to display my configurable products in the best sales static block

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having a small problem with my magento I can not make my configurable product appears in the best sales

Comment: Is it a static block? be more specific.

Comment: {{block type="productcarousel/product_default_bestseller" template="catalog/product/productcarousel/carouselblocks/bestseller.phtml"}} Here is what I have in my home page

Comment: that's an extension right? if it is an extension then it will have some settings for you to change in the backend.

Comment: I will explain: I install a theme and in the settings you can display the best products. but I noticed that his works with simple products

Comment: i understood that but i see that you are trying to use product carousel, that particular module must have some settings for you in the backend, in order to change the products you want it to show.

Comment: I show you what I have http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/937645Capturede769cran20150527a768110819.png

Comment: You have an idea? You have skype so that I show you?

Comment: try enter instead of bestseller.phtml -> configurable.phtml and see what happens.

Comment: I have change the name of the configurable.phtml file but nothing helps

Comment: you don't have to change the name of the file. If you did please change it back to what it was.

Comment: I make the change its still does not : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/502517Capturede769cran20150527a768115842.png , http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/708282Capturede769cran20150527a768115913.png

Comment: {block type="productcarousel/configurable" template="catalog/product/productcarousel/carouselblocks/configurable.phtml"}

Comment: It gives me something but not the products : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/355372Capturede769cran20150527a768120751.png

Comment: do you have skype?

Comment: yes but i am at work now.

Comment: OK no worries give me your name I added you and they speak about it later

Comment: made me sign when you are available

Comment: UP help me please !!

Comment: Add me on skype: grosykevin